# Why adBlock doesn't like the string

Tags: javascript, regex, adblock

My website was loading for really a long time if user have installed adBlock..

I founded out that the reason of it is query.preload.js file. I guess that the problem was the string:

```
var imgUrls = cssPile.match(/[^(]+.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)/g);
```

The problem is in regex to get a string of between a "(" and a ".filename", as it's written in the code comments.

```
cssPile is string getting with .cssText method.
```

So do anybody knows why adBlock doesn't like the strgin I'm talikng about?

I'd be also happy if anybody could write another regex. And if it doesn't cause this problem, it will solve all my problems :)

Comment: What makes you think that the problem is query.preload.js?

Comment: When I comment the string or just remove the regex everythig is OK.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this regex? It doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: It is the string from query.preload.js from here: http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-preload-css-images/

Comment: Technically, the dot should  be escaped because it is a metacharacter, and you want to match a literal dot. But, what happens if imgUrls is empty? Somehow, debug into it with some prints, especially `cssPile`.

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem with the regexp except for "." which would be better escaped but anyway it should work as it is now. If I got it right, the regexp should deal with strings like that:
(filename.gif(filename2.jpeg

I don't see any closing parentheses in your regexp. Give an example of a string it should parse, please